# GnuPG support for ISA crypto extensions

Tags: gpg, cryptography

For performing some results comparison, I was searching online for usages of 'gpg' command with hardware crypto extensions enabled/disabled (eg. AES-NI and ARM NEON), but found none. Instead I find a 6 yrs old [post](https://lists.gnupg.org/pipermail/gnupg-users/2015-March/053061.html) stating this feature is disabled for AES-NI (no information found for ARM NEON). On the other hand, I came across this recent [manual](https://gnupg.org/documentation/manuals/gcrypt.pdf) which allows users to disable supported hardware features (intel-aesni and arm-neon). But I don't find this option  working now, atleast on my Ubuntu VM. How can I make the changes in the mentioned file ‘/etc/gcrypt/hwf.deny’ take effect?

Answer (score 0):

> I don't find this option working now, atleast on my Ubuntu VM.

Putting `intel-aesni` and `arm-neon` on two separate lines in `/etc/gcrypt/hwf.deny` should work to disable both of these features **as long as this file is in your VM's file system.**

> How can I make the changes in the mentioned file `/etc/gcrypt/hwf.deny` take effect?

The changes should take effect immediately after the contents of `/etc/gcrypt/hwf.deny` are saved.

You can view currently enabled hardware features with the command `gpg --list-gcrypt-config | grep 'hwflist'`.

Comment: Sorry for the delay in reply. Somehow my earlier VM got corrupted and I created a new one (Ubuntu 21.04). I am right now trying to see the list of enabled/disabled features on the default gpg package which comes with this Ubuntu version. I don't find any such command option in gpg's help menu. Do you know any way to find out this information?

Comment: It's listed in the manual ( `man gpg`). The command I gave in the answer will show you exactly which hardware features are currently enabled. `list-gcrypt-config` will "Display various internal configuration parameters of Libgcrypt", which is the part of gpg that handles crypto operations. The line starting with `hwflist` shows which hardware features are enabled.